# error in linq query and combobox

Tags: linq, combobox

What's the problem with this code:

```
_department.valuemember = "id";

 var query = db.table.asqueryable();
 query  = query.Where(d => d.departmentID   == _depatment.SelectedValue as int?  );
```

I get this error:
Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

I changed the code and the problem resolved:

```
int selectedvalue = int.parse(_department.selectedvalue.tostring());
query  = query.Where(d => d.departmentID   == selectedvalue  );
```

thank you cameron :)

Comment: Is _depatment.SelectedValue a typo? Should it be _department.SelectedValue? Also, I would recommend that you don't cast to a nullable int.

Comment: _department is a dotnetbar combobox, what can it  be? , if i don't cast i get error